# How can I write "The function $f$ is entirely positive or entirely negative on the interval $ I $" using only mathematical notations

Tags: notation

I'm trying to write "The function $f$ is entirely positive or entirely negative on the interval $ I $" using only mathematical notations.  My first try was:
$$
\forall x \in I \quad f \left ( x \right ) > 0   \; \lor \; f \left( x \right ) < 0
$$

But the above means that there are no $ a \in I $ such that $ f \left ( a \right ) = 0 $.

$$
\left ( \forall x \in I \quad f \left ( x \right ) > 0 \right ) \; \lor \; \left ( \forall x \in I \quad f \left ( x \right ) < 0 \right )
$$

This might be an alternative, but I think it's just too messy.

Also, because of the context, I can't write like this:
$$
\forall x_{1}, x_{2} \in I \quad f \left ( x_{1} \right ) f \left( x_{2} \right ) > 0
$$

How can I write the statement properly? (Also, is the second version good enough?)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second one is the way to go. The third one is a tricky way to state it (a bit convoluted, in my opinion).

Comment: As a typographical advice, keep in mind that using different variables even when not strictly necessary may improve readability.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks :D

Comment: You could just say "$f>0$ or $f<0$ on $I$". This doesn't allow pointwise variation.